# CUDA 7.5 + OSX 10.10.5 Yosemite fatal error: 'string.h' or any other STL headers

Tags: macos, stl, cuda, osx-yosemite, opencv3.0

I am trying to use cuda toolkit, I've downloaded the latest one 7.5 from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cuda-75-release-candidate) - installed. Then got to Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/samples and trying to build a any samples, but getting an error for any STL headers. I am trying to build it with make or nvcc. Here is what I am trying to do:

`cd /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/samples/0_Simple/clock && make`

Here is the output:

```html
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin clang++ -I../../common/inc  -m64  -Xcompiler -arch -Xcompiler x86_64  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 -o clock.o -c clock.cu
In file included from <built-in>:174:
In file included from <command line>:9:
In file included from /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/../include/cuda_runtime.h:112:
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/../include/common_functions.h:65:10: fatal error: 'string.h' file not found
#include <string.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [clock.o] Error 1
```

And here is what it shows when I run `nvcc --verbose clock.cu`

```html
#$ _SPACE_= 
#$ _CUDART_=cudart
#$ _HERE_=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin
#$ _THERE_=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin
#$ _TARGET_SIZE_=
#$ _TARGET_DIR_=
#$ _TARGET_SIZE_=64
#$ TOP=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/..
#$ NVVMIR_LIBRARY_DIR=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/../nvvm/libdevice
#$ PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/../open64/bin:/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/../nvvm/bin:/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin:/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin:/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.0/bin:/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin
#$ INCLUDES="-I/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/../include"  
#$ LIBRARIES=  "-L/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/../lib"
#$ CUDAFE_FLAGS=
#$ PTXAS_FLAGS=
#$ clang -D__CUDA_ARCH__=200 -E -x c++        -DCUDA_DOUBLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS  -D__CUDACC__ -D__NVCC__  "-I/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/../include"   -D"__CUDACC_VER__=70513" -D"__CUDACC_VER_BUILD__=13" -D"__CUDACC_VER_MINOR__=5" -D"__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__=7" -include "cuda_runtime.h" -m64 "clock.cu" > "/var/folders/gy/dzj7qpvd2t90c8c8x1lqd7gw0000gn/T//tmpxft_0000a22e_00000000-9_clock.cpp1.ii" 
In file included from <built-in>:174:
In file included from <command line>:9:
In file included from /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/../include/cuda_runtime.h:112:
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/../include/common_functions.h:65:10: fatal error: 'string.h' file not found
#include <string.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
# --error 0x1 --
```

Anybody had something similar or maybe have some ideas how to fix this?

p.s. originally wanted to build opencv3 with gnu support, but got the same error, then went to check if samples work.

Comment: Do you have XCode 6  installed?

Comment: Including the command line tools? (I remember they were necessary to get the headers)

Comment: Yep, I have command line tools also installed

Comment: Reinstalling command line tools helped, after that I've got this error: "vectorAddDrv.cpp:23:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream> ". If I add -I/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 to make file it solves the problem. Now I have:  "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::string::find_last_of(char, unsigned long)".

Seems like I need to specify the std library to link, @talonmies do you know by any chance how to specify it?

Comment: I have this exact problem (unresolved) on 10.11.3 with CUDA 7.5

Answer (score 1):

In response to OPs final comment you want to add `-stdlib=libc++` to your makefile.